# Failing to call a function after AJAX completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, events

I have a function named `ajaxCall` which makes an AJAX call. I have another function called `filterItem`. On button click of filter I want the `ajaxCall` function to fire so that all items can be retrieved then the `filterItem` function should fire and filter items. However this function is not triggered.

```
$(document).on('click', '.items', function() {
    ajaxCall().promise().done(function() {
        alert();
        console.log("trigger");
        filterItem();
    });
});
```

Comment: Show the `ajaxCall()` script

Comment: Also check the console for errors

Comment: Is code is right ? i am calling two function in  a right way? I am not getting error nor alert it means function is not getting trigger @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @satpal  ajax-call is working on windows.scroll event .

Comment: Are you sure its returning `.promise()`? I am afraid anyone will be able without making wild guesses

Comment: @KumarSubham please show us the code of the `ajaxCall()` and `filterItem()` functions. We cannot help you without seeing them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i cant show codes as ajaxCall function carry some imp data . i am not using promise , i want to know how to trigger first ajaxCall function on click then another function after ajaxCall function is trigger

Comment: Then remove the important data and show us your logic only. You say you're not using promise, yet the code above *relies* on it...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan code to long not able to post on comment

Comment: Then it seems no one can help you as you've not given us enough information. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan posting new question

Answer (score 0):

In Ajax call there is an `async` Property make it `false` and it should work. No need to use `.promise()`

```
$.Ajax({
type:  "Post",
url: "Your URL",
async: false,
success : function(){
alert("ajax Complete");
}
});
```

You can also call your dependent function in Success block if it is possible in your scenario.

Comment: ajaxcall has another function for calling item has in it .

Comment: update your question by adding your both functions in it.